# Using print stylesheet, page overflows to two pages in print preview

Tags: css, printing, stylesheet

I am using a CSS print stylesheet to provide an alternate style to the page elements when printed, and to hide the ones we don't wish to be printed.

When the page is previewed in the browser (tested with IE8), it overflows onto a second page, even though all of the elements appear to fit on a single page.

What has to change in the print stylesheet to prevent this and keep the page to a single printed page? I tried setting display:none to the bottom-most panels, yet the page is still broken up into two.

Also, how to prevent display of the border around the page and the page numbering?

**CSS stylesheet**

```
/* Specify class for items that should not print */
.noprint
{
    display: none;
}

/* Ensure the content spans the full width */
.fullwidth
{
    width: 100%; margin: 0; float: none;
}

/* PRINT STYLES FOR ELEMENTS */
.newscript
{ 
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    margin: 0pt auto;
    clear: both;
    /* background-image: url(    '../_images/blank_rx.jpg' ); */ 

    width: 433pt;
    height: 400pt;
    /* height: 550pt; */
    /* position: relative; */

    font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

.script2, #patientdetails
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    color: #3A5A85;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-weight: bold;           
}

.newscript .doctor
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 10pt;
    top: 10pt;
    width: 400pt;
    height: 80pt;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3A5A85;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-weight: bold;        
}

.newscript .hr1
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 5pt;
    top: 120pt;
    height: 3pt;
    width: 450pt;
    color: #0a0a0a;        
}

.newscript .patientnameLbl
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    color: #000000;    
    left: 18pt;
    top:125pt;
    font-size: 24pt;        
}

.newscript .patientname
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 24pt;
    top: 150pt;
    font-size: 24pt;        
}

.newscript .DOBLbl
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    color: #000000;    
    left: 350pt;
    top: 125pt;
    font-size: 24pt;        
}

.newscript .dob
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 350pt;
    top: 150pt;
    font-size: 24pt;        
}

.newscript .hr2
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 5pt;
    top: 180pt;
    height: 3pt;
    width: 450pt;
    color: #0a0a0a;        
}

.newscript .addressLbl
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    color: #000000;
    left: 18pt;
    top: 190pt;
    font-size: 24pt;        
}

.newscript .address
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 24pt;
    top: 220pt;
    font-size: 24pt;        
}

.newscript .dateLbl
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    color: #000000;    
    left: 352pt;
    top: 190pt;
    font-size: 24pt;        
}

.newscript .currentDate
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 352pt;
    top: 220pt;
    border-bottom: dotted 1pt #000000;
    font-size: 24pt;    
}

.newscript .hr3
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 5pt;
    top: 304pt;
    height: 3pt;
    width: 450pt;
    color: #0a0a0a;        
}

.newscript .rxlogo 
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 18pt;
    top: 314pt;
    width: 28pt;
    height: 33pt;        
}

.newscript .lbldrugname
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 75pt;
    top: 314pt;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 20pt; */
    /* font-family: "Times New Roman"; */
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: left;          
}

.newscript .drugname
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 75pt;
    top: 340pt;
    /* height: 30pt; */
    /* width: 310pt; */
    font-size: 24pt;    
    border: solid 0pt #ccc; 
    background-color: #ffffff;        
}

.newscript .lblstrength
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 75pt;
    top: 370pt;
    /* width: 360pt; */
    /* height: 20pt; */
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: left;


}

.newscript .strength
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 75pt;
    top: 395pt;
    /* height: 20pt; */
    /* width: 310pt; */
    font-size: 24pt;
    border: solid 0pt #ccc;  
    background-color: #ffffff;           
}

.newscript .lbldForm
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 75pt;
    top: 430pt;
    /* width: 100pt;
    height: 20pt; */
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: left;       
}

.newscript .dForm
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 75pt;
    top: 460pt;
    /* height: 20pt;
    width: 125pt; */
    font-size: 24pt;
    border: solid 0pt #ccc; 
    background-color: #ffffff;        
}


.newscript .lblQuantity
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 75pt;
    top: 490pt;
    /* width: 100pt;
    height: 20pt; */
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: left;        
}


.newscript .Quantity
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 75pt;
    top: 520pt;
    /* height: 20pt;
    width: 75pt; */
    font-size: 24pt;
    border: solid 0pt #ccc;      
    background-color: #ffffff;        
}

.newscript .lblDaysSupply
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 75pt;
    top: 550pt;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 20pt; */
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: left;        
}

.newscript .DaysSupply
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    left: 75pt;
    top: 580pt;
    /* height: 20pt; */
    /* width: 100%;  */
    font-size: 24pt;
    border: solid 0pt #ccc; 
    background-color: #ffffff;

    float: none;
}

.newscript .lblSig
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 15pt;
    top: 610pt;
    width: 100pt;
    height: 20pt;
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: left;


}

.newscript .Sig
{
    /* 75 225 */
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 15pt;
    top: 640pt;
    width: 450pt;
    height: 80pt;    
    font-size: 24pt;
    border: solid 1pt #ccc;
    background-color: #ffffff;      
}

.newscript .hr4
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 5pt;
    top: 720pt;
    height: 3pt;
    width: 450pt;
    color: #0a0a0a;        
}

.newscript .txtDaw
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 80pt;
    top: 730pt;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: center;    
}

.newscript .lblrefills
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 15pt;
    top: 765pt;    
    font-size: 24pt;


}

.newscript .refillnum
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 100pt;
    top: 765pt;
    /* width: 35pt;
    height: 20pt; */ 
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: solid 0pt #ccc; 
    background-color: #ffffff;        
}

.newscript .daw
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 185pt;
    top: 800pt;
    width: 60pt;
    height: 30pt;
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: solid 1pt #ccc;
    background-color: #ffffff;


}

.newscript .lblDaw
{
    position: absolute;
    float: none;

    left: 100pt;
    top: 840pt;      
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: center;        
}
```

**ASPX page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" CodeFile="print_newrx.aspx.cs" Inherits="RxVue.print_newrx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/newrx.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/print_rx.css" media="print" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <asp:Panel ID="newscript" runat="server" CssClass="newscript fullwidth">
            <asp:Panel ID="doctor" runat="server" CssClass="doctor fullwidth">
                <asp:Literal ID="docDetails" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Panel ID="patientinfo" runat="server" CssClass="patientinfo fullwidth">
               <asp:Literal ID="patientDetails" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
               <asp:Panel ID="script2" runat="server">                
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDrugName" runat="server" Text="Drug Name" CssClass="lbldrugname"></asp:Label>                                                                                                                   
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblstrengthAndUM" runat="server" Text="Strength:" CssClass="lblstrength"></asp:Label>
                    <br />                    
                    <asp:Label ID="lblForm" runat="server" Text="Form:" CssClass="lbldForm"></asp:Label>
                    <br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text="Quantity:" CssClass="lblQuantity"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="frmquantity" runat="server" CssClass="Quantity"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblDaysSupply" runat="server" Text="Days Supply:" CssClass="lblDaysSupply"></asp:Label>


                    <asp:Label ID="lblSig" runat="server" Text="Sig:" CssClass="lblSig"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <hr class='hr4'/>
                    <div class="txtDaw">THIS PRESCRIPTION WILL BE FILLED GENERICALLY<br />UNLESS THE PRESCRIBER WRITES 'd a w' IN THE BOX BELOW </div>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblrefills" runat="server" Text="Refills:" CssClass="lblrefills"></asp:Label>
                    <br />                                                                             
                    <div class="lblDaw">DISPENSE AS WRITTEN</div>            
               </asp:Panel>
            </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="newscriptbottom" runat="server" CssClass="newscriptbottom noprint">
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancelNew" runat="server" Text="Back" CssClass="btn_newScript noprint" OnClick="btnCancelNew_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" CssClass="btn_newScript noprint" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="window.print();"/>      
    </asp:Panel>   

    </form>

    </asp:Content>
```

**Rendered HTML with body tag styled**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    RxVue
</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/main.css" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/newrx.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/print_rx.css" media="print" />
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/print_rx.css" />


    <!--[if IE]>
    <style>
    fieldset {
        position: relative;
    }
    legend {
        position: absolute;
        top: -.5em;
        left: .2em;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="mainwrap">
        <div id="wrap" class="clearfix">
            <div id="header" class="noprint">
                <!--<h1>RxVue v2.0</h1><img src="images\title.jpg"-->
            </div>
            <div id="topnav" class="noprint">
                <div id="ctl00_buttons">

                    <div id="ctl00_nousers">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Patient.aspx">Search Patients</a></li>
                            <li id="favs"><a href="favorites.aspx">Favorites</a></li>

                            <li style="float:right"><a href="help.aspx">Help</a></li>
                            <li style="float:right"><a href="SessEnd.aspx">Log Off</a></li>

                        </ul>

    </div>


</div>
            </div>
            <div id="main" class="fullwidth">

    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="print_newrx.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBAKXxtXKAgL9pNLfAwL+95vYCQKrtLS2BiSIbnbb9KvUH1ZSdz1FkSgkv3bVd6X5jUkQVgpkQliz" />
</div>


    <div id="ctl00_mainContent_newscript" class="newscript fullwidth">

            <div id="ctl00_mainContent_doctor" class="doctor fullwidth">

                 GOYAL<br/><br/><br/>ELMSFORD, NY 10523<br/>(914)681-2028

    </div>

            <div id="ctl00_mainContent_patientinfo" class="patientinfo fullwidth">

               <div id='patientdetails'><hr class='hr1'/><div class='patientnameLbl'>Patient's Name</div><div class='patientname'>TEST, OPUS</div><hr class='hr2'/><div class='addressLbl'>Address</div><div class='address'>2 SMITH LN<br/>KINGS PARK NY 11754<br/>Home: (999)999-9999 Work: </div><div class='dateLbl'>Date</div><div class='currentDate'>7/14/2011</div><div class='DOBLbl'>DOB</div><div class='dob'>5/18/1965</div><hr class='hr3'/><div class='rxlogo'><img src='_images/newrx_rxlogo.gif'/></div><div class='drugname'>IBUPROFEN</div><div class='strength'>400MG</div><div class='dForm'>TAB</div><div class='Quantity'>10</div><div class='DaysSupply'>10</div><div class='Sig'>
1 DAILY </div><div class='refillnum'>0</div><div class='daw'></div></div>
               <div id="ctl00_mainContent_script2">

                    <span id="ctl00_mainContent_lblDrugName" class="lbldrugname">Drug Name</span>                                                                                                                   
                    <br />
                    <span id="ctl00_mainContent_lblstrengthAndUM" class="lblstrength">Strength:</span>
                    <br />                    
                    <span id="ctl00_mainContent_lblForm" class="lbldForm">Form:</span>
                    <br />

                    <span id="ctl00_mainContent_lblQuantity" class="lblQuantity">Quantity:</span>
                    <input name="ctl00$mainContent$frmquantity" type="text" id="ctl00_mainContent_frmquantity" class="Quantity" />
                        <br />

                    <span id="ctl00_mainContent_lblDaysSupply" class="lblDaysSupply">Days Supply:</span>


                    <span id="ctl00_mainContent_lblSig" class="lblSig">Sig:</span>
                    <br />
                    <hr class='hr4'/>
                    <div class="txtDaw">THIS PRESCRIPTION WILL BE FILLED GENERICALLY<br />UNLESS THE PRESCRIBER WRITES 'd a w' IN THE BOX BELOW </div>
                    <span id="ctl00_mainContent_lblrefills" class="lblrefills">Refills:</span>
                    <br />                                                                             
                    <div class="lblDaw">DISPENSE AS WRITTEN</div>            

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

    <div id="ctl00_mainContent_newscriptbottom" class="newscriptbottom noprint">

        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainContent$btnCancelNew" value="Back" id="ctl00_mainContent_btnCancelNew" class="btn_newScript noprint" />
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainContent$btnPrint" value="Print" onclick="window.print();" id="ctl00_mainContent_btnPrint" class="btn_newScript noprint" />      

</div>   

    </form>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="clearfooter"></div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <span class="image">
            <img src="_images/poweredby.gif" alt="Powered By WebRx"/></span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is contained in patientDetails literal on the aspx page in a hierarchy of divs. The labels follow the patientDetails literal in sequence, I had to keep using position:absolute in order to position each div of each label next to each corresponding content div. It displays ok in IE8 and other browsers.

As far as the 2 page printing issue - Reducing the sizes did not help... However I found what was causing it to break onto another page -
another stylesheet in the hierarchy was defining the #mainwrap with a 1px border. Overriding the border values to 0px in the printing stylesheet no longer displays the border on the second page and keeps the printout to one page.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the style `float:left` to the main table where you have all the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the default margin/padding on body or the document.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Mrchief, I added the body style to the stylesheet, I am still seeing the same results.

Comment: Can you post the rendered html?

Comment: Looks like some styles are missing. The HTML doesn't render nicely. Can you post all the relevant css classes?

Comment: The print stylesheet is used only when the page is printed. The rendered html I posted is generated from the web page using the standard stylesheet, not the print stylesheet. I don't know of a way to view html source from print preview or the print dialog. Is there a way to view html source that is generated for the page to be printed, when the print stylesheet is used?

Comment: Well, you can take out `media=print` and remove the main stylesheet.

Comment: Good point. :)  I've changed the stylesheet to use the print stylesheet, and replaced the rendered html above with the hmtl rendered from the print stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

You have a ton of elements with `position:absolute;` in your stylesheet.

IE7 & 8 tend to choke on those in print mode.

Try positioning your content normally and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Once I removed all position:absolute, the div's are better positioned. However the issue with the page being broken up into two pages still persists.

Comment: I've placed the screen captures of how the print preview looks like with the web page broken into two pages here: [screen captures](http://sashka.com)

Comment: @Alexander, reduce the font sizes for the headers and the text and it should fit.

Comment: I will try this and let you know.. Is there a way to eliminate that border, "Page #", and the url on the bottom?